# Is there a special variable containing a case statement match

Tags: bash, case

If you write a Bash `case` statement, can you get the current match without explicitly assigning it to a variable ?

Consider

```
case $(some subshell command sequence) in
  one) stuff ;;
  *) stuff "$case_match";;
esac
```

I know that I can do the below but wanted to be more succinct.

```
case_match=$(some subshell command sequence)
case "$case_match" in
...
```

Is there a special variable representing `$case_match` ?

---

Following comment from *@Hauke Laging* another contrived example. You can do this:

```
today=$(date '+%A')
case "$today" in
  *) echo "It's $today" ;;
esac
```

But it would be nice to do this - the question asked if this was possible (but it isn't):

```
case $(date '+%A') in
  *) echo "It's $case_match" ;;
esac
```

(where `case_match` is the golden variable that eludes us)

Comment: @Hauke Laging - yes you can. I'll add a contrived example to the question to illustrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with a bit of a hack, but you need to be sure you have an unset variable available. For example:

```
unset foo  # Make sure foo is unset, or at least set to the empty string
case ${foo:-$(date +%m)} in
   1) echo "Jan" ;;
   2) echo "Feb" ;;
 # ...
  11) echo "Nov" ;;
  12) echo "Dec" ;;
esac
```

Here, `foo` is being used as a dummy variable solely to allow the default parameter expansion to produce the output of the command substition.

Comment: Yes, I've used this technique before but it is a little brittle. I think as a solution for `bash` this is probably as good as it gets!

Answer (score 5):

No.

With `zsh -o extendedglob` however you can do:

```
case $(cmd) in
  ((#m)*) printf '%s\n' "Match: $MATCH"
esac
```

`(#m)` is the [*globbing flag*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Globbing-Flags) to enable `$MATCH`. It's more useful in things like `${var//(#m)?/<$MATCH>}`.

Or:

```
case $(cmd) in
  ((#b)(???)(*)) printf '%s\n' "First 3 chars: $match[1], rest: $match[2]"
esac
```

`(#b)` for enabling *back-references*.

Or (without needing `extendedglob`):

```
case ${output::=$(cmd)} in
  (*) printf '%s\n' "Output: $output"
esac
```